# ID a funky (old?) very distinctive bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

This bike I found on a Brazilian mountain bike Instagram page, they caption it as a bow and arrow with wheels.

Anyone ever seen this strange looking beauty before? I can't quite tell but it might be an early folding bike. I'm saying is old because it's got a rod brake.

[image]

Comment: Never seen anything like it.  Probably not a very good "mountain" bike, as the frame would not be very strong (unless the materials are very heavy).  I'm curious about the stuff under the diagonal tube -- looks like it might be a mechanism for folding somehow.

Comment: Looks like it might be from same project as these: https://www.behance.net/gallery/35437979/Velocipedia. Note that there's a lever for rod brake but no brake.

Comment: Wow, looks like I was wrong and it's a real bike with all the design flaws. The photos show that the brake is not usual rod brake but a spoon brake that is hidden inside steerer tube.

Comment: I wonder if the photo in the question is actually of a reconstruction -- it doesn't *quite* match the Gérard, as it only has a single top/down tube rather than the parallel pair.  The Gérard also has a chunky hinge that's missing from the above picture, and obvious saddle rails  that could pass for steam train parts. I assume it's a physical reconstruction rather than just a computer model -- surely no one would put those mismatched tyres on a computer model

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very old military bike, estimates say circa 1898, credited to a French officer and cycling advocate Captain Gerrard (although actually probably designed by someone else). It is indeed a folding bike, one of the first of its kind. Soldiers on bicycle were a relatively common thing prior to the first world war. Lots more information here, [The BSA & Military Bicycle Museum](https://bsamuseum.wordpress.com/1898-1914-peugeot-captain-gerard-folding-bicycle/) ; and here [Captain Gerard history](http://vintagebikescollection.com/captain_gerard_history/en)

[image: Vintage advertisement for a 1912 Captain Gerard folding bicycle]
[image: Patent description for 1899 Captain Gerard folding bicycle]

Answer (score 2):

That's art, not a bike.  Its not intended to be ridden.

If you did try and ride it, your first hard take-off would likely flip you backwards unless you were out of the saddle and leaning forward.

Braking would be quite good, assuming its a fixed gear and not just a single-speed.  The weight distribution would put more on the rear helping with skid stops.  But the pedals lack retainer straps or clipsless pedals, so its not a real fixie.

As noted, the front brake is absent, and the hand lever is just for show.

If you got it rolling okay, it would be a floppy horror to steer.  That front wheel will want to turn 90 to the left or right, so requires strength to hold it up.

**Answer** its a show bike not for riding.  What a waste of time and effort.

Comment: Not to mention the first time you hit a bump, it’ll crack where the top tube meets the seat tube.

Comment: It's like one of these hipster Strida bikes. Nice to look at but an unstable horror to ride...